# How to change the height of div while a validate in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

How to change the height of div while a validate in jquery

this div containing the error message. div should update its height when ever 
the message is updated

```
  errorPlacement : function(error, element) {

        $('#error_container').show();
        error.appendTo($('#error_container'));
        $('#error_container').append("<br>");
    },
```

i tried to apply

```
     $("#error_container").attr({ 
          height: "auto"
        });
```

but did not get proper place for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I've also changed your 
 addition to bottom padding instead, so you can easily remove it.

```
errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
  $('#error_container').show();
  error.appendTo($('#error_container'));
  $('#error_container').css('padding-bottom', '20px');
  $("#error_container").css('height', 'auto');
},
```

If you need to undo the padding, you can do:

```
  $('#error_container').css('padding-bottom', '0');
```

Comment: where to put this in validate method

Comment: I suggest using padding instead of a <br> tag - I've edited my answer again. Let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: If i want to use -> symbol with error message how can i remove that. we have success: function(label){} method to handle this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16176/discussion-between-amit-and-zenkaty)

Answer (score 1):

set it like this

```
$("#error_container").css('height', 'auto');
```

Comment: where to put this in validate method.

Comment: but when it is not in errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
 it should be update.

Comment: you can try it above jquery call

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$("#error_container").attr("style","height:auto");
```

Or use `.css()` like this;

```
$("#error_container").css('height', 'auto');
```